# Windows service debugging error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

when I try to do tools-> attach to process and select windows service I get:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information:



C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProj\Service\myproj.dll



To debug this module, change its project build configuration to Debug mode. To suppress this message, disable the 'Warn if no user code on launch' debugger option.
---------------------------
OK
```

---

when I do following:

Tools -> options -> Debugging and uncheck "Warn if no user code on launch", the error goes but debugger point not hit. Please suggest solution.

Thanks

Comment: Did you make sure that the library is being compiled in Debug mode instead of Release mode? All you've done at this point is suppress the error message (kinda pointless).

Comment: @Joel How can I check that the library is compiled in debug mode and if not how to set it. do I need to rebuild after this ?

Comment: In the properties of your projects (the windows service and any dll projects that are being run with it), you need to go to the `Build` tab and select `Debug` under the configuration selection at the top.

Comment: @Joel: I have done that but still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Under `"Tools--->Options---->Debugging"` uncheck `"Enable Just My Code(Managed Only)"`